# Не могу понять в чем проблема

Tags: c

[image: lcl]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)

{
    float weight;/*вес*/
    float value;/*платиновый эквивалент*/

    printf("Хотите узнать свой вес в платиновом эквиваленте?\n");
    printf("Давайте подсчитаем.\n");
    printf("Пожалуйста,введите свой вес, выраженный в футах: ");

    /*получить входные данные от пользователя*/

    scanf("%f", &weigth);
    /*считаем что родия равна $1700 за тройскую унцию*/
    /*14.5833 коффициент для перевода веса, выраженного в фунтах, в тройские унции*/
    value = 1700.0 * weight * 14.5833;

    printf("Ваш вес в платиновом  эквиваленте составляет $%.2f.\n" ,value);
    printf("Вы легко можете стать достойным этого!Если цена платины падает,\n");
    printf("ешьте больше для поддержания своей стоимости.\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Не понимаю! Компилятор ясно и четко написал - необъявленный идентификатор. Неужели просто лень посмотреть на то, что он пишет, но не лень набирать вопрос и присовокуплять к нему копию экрана?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имя переменной не weigth а weight
`scanf("%f",&weight);`